# Assign a cell based on the result of another formula

Tags: excel

I want to get a date (in this example row 1, col 2) depending on the number of entries in row 2. I can get the Number of entries with Count() which gives me 2.

Since I need the date in the cell in row 3 and column 1 this formula would do the trick with hard coded numbers

```
=R(-2)C(1)
```

But the following formula does not like to get the second number from a formula. To simplify the formula I have the result of count in the cell below. I tried to use

```
=R(-2)C(R(1)C)
```

This results in a reference error. (The count formula is not the real one, it had too many R and C stuff )

Does anyone know what I could do instead? I want to avoid having a row of IF conditions in the formula.

I try to make it clearer:

```
|2015-01-01|2015-02-01|2015-03-01|
|   1634   |   214    |          |
|=formula()|          |          |
|=count(row2)|        |          |

where formula() = Date_from_row1_where_last_value_in_row_2
```

Comment: Yeah, you can't make a cell reference a variable.  The best you can do is park the result somewhere, and reference that.

Comment: "...since I need the date in the  cell in row 24 and column 1..." - How do you know to look at that cell?  Can you explain how the `count()` fits in? Is it `Count() + 4` to determine the row to look in?

Comment: @BruceWayne : I know that the date is in line one and the count just tells me how many cells in line two have values in them. The last column which has a value in it in line 2 is the column I need the date from row 1.

Comment: This feels like a job for `=indirect()` but I don't understand what you are doing here at all. Maybe some sample data or a picture of your sheet or some other clues would be helpful.

Comment: @durbnpoisn : How can I reference it?

Comment: `=Offset(R1C1,COUNTA(R2))`?

Comment: Also, are you using R1C1 for any specific reason?

Comment: @BruceWayne I just thought it would be easier than figuring out the AB stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for your formula (assuming your Dates are in row 1):

`=Index(R1,,count(R2))`

To explain briefly: It will return a cell in row 1 (the "index").  We know which cell, because the `count(r2)` counts how many cells have info in that row, then returns the cell in that column, row 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Offset` function and `COUNT`.  The `COUNT` function determines how many columns (assumed they are contiguous) have data in Row 2. Row 2 here is hardcoded, since there is no indication that you need it to be otherwise.

```
=OFFSET(R1C1,0,COUNT(R2)-1)
```

This formula returns the restulting value in the cell which is offset 0 rows (IOW, the same row) as cell R1C1, and the # of columns offset by the Count function.

Comment: Is this equivalent to the index function? It has a terrible german translation though ...

Comment: @Kazschuri - this will return the same thing, yes.  It's just written differently (as you may know, there's more than one way to skin a cat, especially in Excel).  It takes the Top Leftmost cell ("A1"), then gets a cell that's offset from there by `0` rows, but `count(r2)-1` columns away.  You do the minus 1 because you're already in column 1. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes, it totally makes sense. Thank you all for the help! I probably can't assign two right answers here?

Comment: @Kazschuri no you can't assign two right answers, but you can "upvote" any answer which has been helpful for you.  Cheers.